# How to avoid Reflected_xss_all_clients vulnerabilities in Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, security, xss, checkmarx

Currently, I am working for a Winforms project.
When I am scanning my Winforms application through CheckMarx then I am getting multiple `Reflected_xss_all_clients` vulnerabilities.
I know there is no scripting in Winforms. `XSS` is a web threat but may be there would be some way to remediate these threats during scanning.

Here is the error code section 1:

```
private void UpdatePreviewValue()
  {
     try
     {
        // Set the preview value
        if (txtFieldValue.Text != string.Empty)
        {
           // Show the preview value
           lblPreview.Text = "(" + txtFieldValue.Text + ")";
        }
        else
        {
           // Show that there is no field value
           lblPreview.Text = Properties.Resources.Std_Txt_Fld_NoFieldValue;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        frmErrorHandler.ShowDataError(Properties.ErrorStrings.ErrorTitle_SrcFldCtlInteger_UpdatePreviewValue, DataErrorImageConstants.Exclamation, ex);
     }
  }
```

in above code section, the line `lblPreview.Text = "(" + txtFieldValue.Text + ")";`is throwing `Reflected_xss_all_clients` vulnerabilities.

Here is the error code section 2:

```
      /// <summary>
      /// Method to copy an existing node for moving inside a grid
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="rowToCopy">GridRow to copy</param>
      /// <returns>GridRow</returns>
      private GridRow CopyGridRow(GridRow rowToCopy)
      {
         GridRow newRow = gridCategories.NewRow();
         newRow.Tag = rowToCopy.Tag;
         newRow.Cells[0].Text = rowToCopy.Cells[0].Text;
         newRow.Cells[0].Image = rowToCopy.Cells[0].Image;
         newRow.Cells[1].Text = rowToCopy.Cells[1].Text;

         if (rowToCopy.HasRows)
         {
            foreach (GridRow nestedRow in rowToCopy.NestedRows)
            {
               newRow.NestedRows.Add(CopyGridRow(nestedRow));
            }
         }

         return newRow;
      }
```

in above code section, the line `newRow.Cells[0].Text = rowToCopy.Cells[0].Text;` and `newRow.Cells[1].Text = rowToCopy.Cells[1].Text;`are throwing `Reflected_xss_all_clients`vulnerabilities.

Here is the error code section 3:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Method used to add a new discrete value to the listview
  /// </summary>
  private void AddDiscreteValue()
  {
     // check we have an entry to add
     if (txtDiscreteValue.Text != "")
     {
        SetDiscreteValue(txtDiscreteValue.Text, true, null, false);
     }
  }
```

In above code section, the line `SetDiscreteValue(txtDiscreteValue.Text, true, null, false);` is throwing Reflected_xss_all_clients vulnerabilities for `txtDiscreteValue.Text`

Please suggest any way to remediate it, if possible.

Comment: I am afraid that *Checkmarx* is considering your project as *WebApp* because of a file with an extension from the Web family. Do you have such a file?

Comment: Just ignore it.

Comment: @baruchiro,
I don't have such file. Is there any way to handle it other than ignoring ?

Comment: @user14285851 I agree with baruchiro, your security team should pick a Checkmarx preset that does not include web-related vulns that is obviously not applicable to your Winforms app. There can also create a new preset through the Preset manager https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/49250315/Preset+Manager

Comment: @RomanCanlas Don't Checkmarx presets apply to the whole solution, rather than individual projects? Am I SOL if my solution includes both Web and Windows Forms projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HtmlSanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/) NuGet package in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score -1):

Checkmarx will follow the string from input to use. Sometimes it identifies a variable which is not fillterd transited to the frontend as a XSS.

As for me, I always ignore the XSS reported from Checkmarx. Maybe you can use a fillter function before use the string variable. Like this

```
     txtFieldValue.Text=cleanXSS(txtFieldValue.Text)
```

As for cleanXSS(), you can find many examples after google.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link of such example.
I tried through google but didn't found.

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/35082068090/